# Docusign Java API: How to prevent users from adding fields?

Tags: docusignapi

When my recipients get their documents to sign, there's a "Fields" colunn on the left side which allows them to add Signatures, Names, etc.  I don't want them to have those options.

Answer (score 1):

If you pre-define tags, signers won't enter the "free form signing" experience and they won't be able to place their own.

Comment: My apologies, I neglected to mention that I'm creating my template (including signers and tabs) using CompositeTemplate and inlineTemplate.

Comment: It sounds like your tags aren't properly being associated with your recipients. Do the templates have matching placeholder role names? Can you edit your question to include the relevant chunk of code?

Comment: Turns out that the person who was running it wasn't using a document with the required PDF field names for transformation, so it didn't have any of my tabs.  All good now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!